# Find an ID in a PHP array and replace it's children

Tags: php, arrays, json

In PHP I'm creating an array consisting out of an ID and a title for something. I'm using json_decode to gather this piece of JSON.

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "a title"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "another title"
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "title": "one more title"
  }
]
```

Now I made a PHP array that consists of the id "1" and the title "a different title" in the same format I initially created the JSON I already have

How do I find the id and title using the id I have to replace the title with my new title?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What if the id 1 is not found? Do you want to add it or just not care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple two liner:
I first take the ids from the array with array_column and use array_diff to remove the id = 1 item.
Then I use this in array_intersect_key to only include id 0 and 2 to the new $arr.
Then I add the $find array as the last item.
No need for looping.

```
$arr = json_decode('[
  {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "a title"
  },
  {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "another title"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "one more title"
  }
]', true);


$find = [
  'id' => 1,
  'title' => 'a different title',
];

$arr = array_intersect_key($arr, array_diff(array_column($arr, "id"), [$find["id"]]));
$arr[] = $find;

Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/a2urf

Answer (score 0):

If want to find element with specific `id` value and replace `title` tag in that with new value, then try following code:

```
$id = 1; //ID to find
$title = "New Title Value";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value["id"] == $id) {
        $value["title"] = $title;
    }
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and set the value to your array where the id's match:

```
$arrays = json_decode('[
  {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "a title"
  },
  {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "another title"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "one more title"
  }
]', true);

$array = [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'a different title',
];

foreach ($arrays as &$value) {
    if ($value['id'] === $array['id']) {
        $value = $array;
    }
}
unset($value);
var_dump($arrays);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9GOsL)

Answer (score -1):

you could try this:

```
$items = json_decode('[
  {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "a title"
  },
  {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "another title"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "one more title"
  }
]', true);

$replace = [
  'id' => 1,
  'title' => 'a different title',
];

$items = array_map(function($item) use($replace) {
   return (int)$item['id'] === (int)$replace['id'] ? $replace : $item;
}, $items);

print_r($items);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php


$str='[{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "a title"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "another title"
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "title": "one more title"
  }]
';
$arr=(array)json_decode($str,true);

//var_dump($arr);

//print_r($arr);

echo($arr[0]['id']);
echo($arr[0]['title']);

echo($arr[1]['id']);
echo($arr[1]['title']);

echo($arr[2]['id']);
echo($arr[2]['title']);
?>
```

Comment: Where do you replace the id 1? And why do you array cast the json_decode?